# How to see history of snap packages updates?

Tags: updates, snap, update-history

Is there way to see which snap packages were updated, and when ?

Something like `snap list` but ordered by last updated packages with specific dates.

Comment: `snap changes`?

Comment: Nice command, but looks like it's showing only most recent changes... currently for me only 2 last installs...

Comment: Please mark yourself as affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1771714) :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`snap changes` will list recent changes, and `snap tasks` will list the steps involved in a change.

It gets garbage-collected after some time (1 day for changes that succeeded, 7 for failures), or after a certain size (500 changes), both of which are currently hardcoded, but it's the commmand you want.

I'll update [lp:1771714](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1771714) to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

A shell command pipeline would be

`snap list | tail -n +2| cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i snap info {} | grep "name:\|  latest/stable:"`

This assumes everything was installed from the `latest` channel.

The output is sorted alpabetically by Snap name.
To sort it by date date descending would require more commands.

Output (truncated)

```
name:    bare
  latest/stable:    1.0 2019-08-21 (5) 4kB -
name:      boxy-svg
  latest/stable:    3.96.0 2023-01-17 (178) 201MB -
name:      core
  latest/stable:    16-2.58                     2023-01-10 (14447) 122MB -
name:      core18
  latest/stable:    20221212 2022-12-21 (2667) 58MB -
name:      core20
  latest/stable:    20221212 2022-12-28 (1778) 66MB -
name:      core22
  latest/stable:    20230110 2023-01-18 (484) 76MB -

...
```

To sort the snap list by date ascending, I have now come up with these 2 command pipelines:

```
snap list | tail -n +2| cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i snap info {} | grep "name:\|  latest/stable:"  > /tmp/snaps-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt

< /tmp/snaps-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt perl -0777 -pE "s/\n\s/\t/gms" - | perl -ple "s/\s+/ /g" | cut -d" " -f 2,5 | sort -k2 -d | column -t -s $' '
```

This first line / set of commands can take a couple of seconds, therefore I write that output into a file in `/tmp`.

Output:

```
bare 2019-08-21
...
boxy-svg 2023-01-17
core22 2023-01-18
postman 2023-01-19
powershell 2023-01-25
```